# Change Angular ui-bootstrap datepicker day order

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Currently the ui-bootstrap datepicker popup orders the days of the week Mon-Sun.
I have a request from a customer to reorder them Sun-Sat

Interestingly, on the ui-bootstrap page, the inline example has the Sun-Mon order but the popup is Mon-Sun.

Is there a way to change the day order in the popup? 
I have not found any info on that topic in my googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew, in the [Datepicker docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker), under the "Popup Settings" subheading, it says "Options for datepicker can be passed as JSON using the datepicker-options attribute", which was the key piece for me in tackling the same problem you're facing.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dksmiffs/v9xemx9p/), which simplifies the example code from angular-ui.github.io, and contains the bits I think you need.  Note that you need to change to camel case "startingDay" spelling:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  showWeeks: false,      
  startingDay: 0
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That plugin has 'starting-day' as an option. Setting that to 0 will make it start on Sunday.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: That only seems to have an effect on the inline variety in the <datepicker> tag, not on the popup calendar.

Comment: Can you show your code? This is the option that does what you are asking for. You can also try using AngularStraps datepicker (that's what I use). http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers#datepickers

Comment: The settings for inline and popup are a bit different. for the inline, you can add starting-day="0" as an attribute within the <datepicker> tag, but this won't work for the popup. Instead you have to add it as a value in the $scope.dateOptions in camelCase as dave pointed out. This was the piece I was missing. All the same, I completely overlooked starting-day.